# Issue in Not operator

Tags: r

Can anyone please help me. Not sure what wrong I am doing here. As per the code I should get the result as "A" right? Or Am i missing something?

```
> asd <- c("A")
> asd1 <- c("B","V")
> asd[asd %in% !(asd %in% asd1)]
character(0)
```

Comment: Run little pieces of your code to understand why it's not working. `asd %in% asd1`, then `!(asd %in% asd1)`... you don't want to check if your `asd` value "A"` is in the result (`TRUE`) of `!(asd %in% asd1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution will return the desired result, you do not need to use `%in%` twice:

```
asd[!(asd %in% asd1)]
[1] "A"
```